# Is it possible to use Native C++ code in ARC?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, google-chrome-arc

We want to try to launch our software on Chrome OS using ARC. Many parts of our software application are written in C++ and compiled using the Android NDK. 
Is it possible to launch this kind of application under ARC?
Is it possible to launch Native applications(or Java + JNI) under ARC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ARM compiled NDK libraries will run on all Chromebooks currently. For ARM machines they run more or less natively.

For non-ARM machines there is a binary translation layer that dynamically converts the code to run on the target machine. This layer may not be 100% machine compatible and if you see errors or crashes indicating instructions cannot be translated, or fundamental differences between your app on ARM and x86, you should file a bug: http://goo.gl/megdlG

Comment: "For non-ARM machines there is a binary translation layer that dynamically converts the code to run on the target machine." Can you provide a source for this information. I am interested in reading into this. I know that android does not have this capability for arm to x86(in my experience), and I have never heard about this capability.

Comment: ARC team hasn't released much info about this yet, so there is no source to link for it yet. It was built originally for ARC, and is not part of android.

Comment: @Theyouthis: Samsung Tab 3, for example, can run ARM-v7a compiled code, but it is significantly slower than comparable ARM-powered device. I am not sure if all other Atom-based devices (ASUS, Lenovo) do this, too. But android x86 includes libhoudini which is universal.

Comment: no i dont believe a x86 android device can run arm or arm7 compiled code, and yes arm7 devices can run arm code with a noticeable performance loss. What is impressive is that they now have the tech for x86 machines to execute armeabi compiled code, with little performance differences. I tried this out yesterday using so files from pdfTron, its like magic.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using a library in my project called PDFtron. It contains ".so" files that I have to assume are either c or c++, and they work fine with Java + JNI. There doesn't seems to be a lot of information out there about how this all works(and what works or doesn't), so please post your findings.

From google spokesperson(taken from arstechnica):

"""The app code is all running on top of the Chrome platform, specifically inside of Native Client. In this way the ARC (App Runtime for Chrome) apps run in the same environment as other apps you can download from the Chrome Web Store, even though they are written on top of standard Android APIs. The developers do not need to port or modify their code, though they often choose to improve it to work well with the Chromebook form factor (keyboard, touchpad, optional touchscreen, etc)."""

In this quote I think the important part is the integration with native client, which is a technology for executing Native code like C and C++ in the browser.